# Language Packages for Edubuntu

Tags: language-support, edubuntu

On a build I use for classroom computers with Ubuntu Mate 16.04LTS I include `ubuntu-edu-primary ubuntu-edu-secondary ubuntu-edu-tertiary`.  I wish to provide these packages in Spanish.  I had done this many years a go and it seemed most packages had language support in ES.  Not most seem to longer be supported.  Am I missing something

Comment: Those are meta packages which depend on a bunch of of other packages providing various education programs. To the extent the program packages contain Spanish translations, the translations should typically come with respective package. Can you please edit your question and provide a couple of examples of programs where Spanish translations appear to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm creating the build on a Virtual Machine.  I started with an English version of the build which had the ubuntu-edu-~ packages installed.  I cloned the English version to save time and installed ES thru the Language Support app.  This is when I came up with missing language packages for the ubuntu-edu packages.

I recently tried a fresh install of the UbuntuMate 16.04 LTS in ES.  Then I added the ubuntu-edu packages.  Everything is ok.  I know it might be interesting to find out what went wrong in my first try.  But I will simply use the fresh ES build to do this project.  There may be other packages that didnt acquire ES and I dont want to scan the entire build for them.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to drag one of the "Español" items to the top of the list in _Language Support_ to make Spanish the current display language. Anyway, since you resolved the problem, please accept this answer as the accepted answer in a couple of days when you can do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is enough, but you can try:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-edu-primary ubuntu-edu-secondary ubuntu-edu-tertiary

sudo apt-get install language-pack-es language-pack-gnome-es \
firefox-locale-es aspell-es  language-pack-es-base hunspell-es \
language-pack-gnome-es-base language-pack-gnome-es \
libreoffice-l10n-es thunderbird-locale-es gimp-help-es calligra-l10n-es \
gcompris-sound-es hyphen-es kde-l10n-es language-pack-kde-es \
libreoffice-help-es manpages-es manpages-es-extra mythes-es \
thunderbird-locale-es-ar thunderbird-locale-es-es wspanish

sudo apt-get install `check-language-support -l es`
```

Otherwise it may be localization issue of desktops for which edu- packages created.